# Suppress page number till table of contents in latex scrreprt and avoid that “contents” appears in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I'm writing my bachelor thesis in the documentclass `scrreprt`.

Unfortunately I can't suppress the page numbering, till the table of contents begins. The first two pages are empty. But then LaTeX starts numerating the pages in roman from 3 to 5, such that on the table of contents page there appears a small v. In addition to that the word contents appears itself in the ToC. I want to avoid this as well.

I was of course experimenting with `\pagestyle{empty}` and a lot of other things I found via googling but no result was appropriate to solve my problem. This what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}  
\usepackage{tocbibind}   
\begin{document}  
\pagestyle{empty}  
%%%% Title page  
\begin{titlepage}
titlepage  
\begin{center}  
\end{center}  
\pagenumbering{roman}  
\vspace*{75mm}  
\end{titlepage}  
blabla  
\newpage  
\thispagestyle{empty}  
\pagestyle{empty}  
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}  
blabla
\newpage  
\pagestyle{empty}  
%%%% summary in mother tongue  
\chapter*{summary}  
\tableofcontents  
\newpage  
\thispagestyle{empty}  
\mbox{}  
\newpage
%%%% Page numbering restarts here  
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\pagestyle{headings}    
\chapter{introduction}
```

I hope I stated the problem clearly.

Edit: I found a very simple solution to the problem that the content appears in itself. The command `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` suppresses that the toc appears.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You are working with a KOMA class. So the package `tocbibind` is counterproductive.

Comment: Hello Marco. I didn't know that this is counterproductive. I wanted to add the bibliography in my ToC and adding this package seemed to be the most reasonable and intuitive way to do so. Why is this counterproductive? Is this package somehow in contradiction to my ambition to suppress the page numbers till the ToC?

Comment: The `KOMA-Script` classes provide the class option `bibliography=totoc`.

Comment: @user2534618: lockstep provides the correct way. It's not relavant to the numbering so it was mentioned in the comment. Your other issue is related to understanding of page numbers. Every page has a logical page. The value of \thepage can be different. So a simple `\clearpage\pagenumbering{roman}` before the command `\tableofcontents` will fix your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. Doing as you said results in a change of the number v to i on the page, where the contents are listed.

Answer (score 7):

When you use commands like `\chapter` and `\tableofcontents` they implicity set `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

You can suppress this behavior in two ways:

- putting `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after each of those commands.

In this case, your MWE can be changed to:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%%%% Title page
\begin{titlepage}
titlepage
\begin{center}
\end{center}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\vspace*{75mm}
\end{titlepage}
blabla
\newpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}\thispagestyle{empty}
blabla
\newpage
%%%% summary in mother tongue
\chapter*{summary}\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
%%%% Page numbering restarts here
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter{introduction}
\end{document}
```

- redefining `\chapterpagestyle` at the beginning of the file and restoring it when you want to start your pages numbered

In this case, your MWE can be changed to:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
%%%% Title page
\begin{titlepage}
titlepage
\begin{center}
\end{center}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\vspace*{75mm}
\end{titlepage}
blabla
\newpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
blabla
\newpage
%%%% summary in mother tongue
\chapter*{summary}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
%%%% Page numbering restarts here
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter{introduction}
\end{document}
```

In both ways your pages are numbered starting with the 'Introduction'.